# Thread suspend and resume inside run()

Tags: java

I implemented multithreading through implemnting `runnable` and overriding `run()`. I want to suspend the thread inside `run()`.

Please Help me

What should I do in `void run(){            }` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this is to call `wait` on some object that another thread can then notify. This would be the pattern for your code:

```
public void run() {
    . . .
    // decide to suspend thread execution:
    synchronized (LOCK) {
        try {
            LOCK.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // thread was interrupted -- time to return?
        }
    }
    // execution resumes here after interrupt or notify
}
```

Then some other thread executes this code:

```
synchronized (LOCK) {
    LOCK.notify(); // or notifyAll();
}
```

In these code fragments, `LOCK` is some object that is accessible to both pieces of code. There's no need for a separate object if it makes sense to use an available object to do the job.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to tell without knowing more details. But your choices are:

- `Thread.sleep()` - and unconditionally sleeping for a while
- `wait/notify` pair to wait on some object
- blocking data structures like [`BlockingQueue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html), waking up the thread when something appears in the collection
- `Thread.join()` to wait on some other thread
- Java 5 concurrency abstractions like [`Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), [`CountDownLatch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), [`CyclicBarrier`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) and many others

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `Object.wait()` and then `Object.notifyAll()`, but it's a tricky thing to use properly. Read up on it. A good source is Effective Java by Josh Bloch.